# xCode Phonegap Build Failing - directory Not found error

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, filenames

Sometimes when we upgrade a phonegap build project and the **www** folder files. The build starts failing. Shell script error comes like below.

```
CAN NOT COPY 'asset/www/img/css/App' to target directory
CAN NOT COPY 'asset/www/img/css/App'
```

This might be due to Spaces in files such as CSS and Images etc. 
If cleaning up Build folder, derived data folder, resetting the var/folder, resetting the simulators does not help than do below thing.
Rename files to REMOVE SPACES. like "App icon.PNG" => "App_icon.PNG"

Answer (score 0):

Piece of Cake!
Just Rename files to REMOVE SPACES. like "App icon.PNG" => "APP_ICON.PNG"